# Ubuntu 20.04 can't persist the Iptables configuration

Tags: 20.04, iptables

I have been doing this in all previous Ubuntu editions without an issue, but something has changed in Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo apt install iptables-persistent

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
...

debconf-set-selections <<< "iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 boolean true"
debconf-set-selections <<< "iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v6 boolean true"
dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
```

Two things I have noticed

1. Despite the settings above, I can't install it silently. I get this screen:
   [image]
   And despite clicking yes the file `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` is empty

> ```
> *filter
> :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
> :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
> :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
> COMMIT
> ```

2. After a reboot, everything is set to the file above. So nothing is saved.

Any advise please?

Answer (score 6):

I can at least answer part of your question, it appears that there is no way to suppress the save prompt during the reconfigure and also have it perform the save.  You can suppress the prompt by setting "iptables-persistent/autosave_done" but that also prevents any saves from happening.  If you want to look at the logic, it's contained in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables-persistent.config` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables-persistent.postinst`.

I have no idea why the reconfigure save isn't working, this sounds silly but can you do a `iptables -t filter -L -n` before you run the reconfigure?  Does it look like you expect?

As a side question, are you running reconfigure for the sole purpose of saving your rules?  If so, it's far easier to do `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 && ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6`

Comment: I can confirm that `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4` correctly saves rules and are available on restart.

Answer (score 3):

**How to save iptables permenantely on ubuntu 20.04?**

here I am going to give port: 80 and 443 rules for incomming

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

installing iptables-persistent

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

if already isntalled then restart it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure iptables-persistent
```

give - YES on both questions

now save iptables permenantley to files:

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v4

sudo ip6tables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

now reboot your ubuntu

```
sudo reboot
```

You will find that all iptables rules will also reload automatically for our ports 80 and 443 incoming.

Comment: Sorry, it did not work for me. I was using port 3306 and copied convoluted rule of port 631 as 3306 in saved /etc/iptables/rule.v4. Command after boot iptables-restore did work. Btw, how come ports 22 and 631 are restored automatically after boot. Could it be that mysql service should open up the required port?

Answer (score 0):

iptables doesn't work anymore with UBUNTU 20.04 since ~febrary 2021.
users must migrate to nftables package. You can install it by use apt or synaptic. https://www.netfilter.org/projects/nftables/index.html

Comment: is that true though? im on 20.04 lts and iptables work for me

Comment: @Dannyboy maybe because there are symbolic links managed by alternatives . You can inspect it with: `update-alternatives --query iptables`

Comment: That's obviously not true. It would mean that kubernetes, for example, wouldn't work at all! Ubuntu 20.04 uses Debian 11, so I suppose it translates the iptables syntax to nftables, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't work. If you want to configure your rules, you can't sense the actual difference.